# Not able to get the data ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I have this react code here which is calling an api.

the first console.log call returned the data but the second console.log is undefined.

Where did I go wrong here? Thanks for pointing my mistakes and greatly appreciated

```
export default class ProfileDetail extends Component {
state = {
    prodetail:'',
}

  async  componentDidMount(){
        const id = this.props.match.params.id           
        const searchurl = `https://www.demo.com/api/personinfo/persondetail?id=${id}`;
        const res = await axios.get(searchurl);
        this.setState({prodetail:res.data});
    }

   render() {
    const{ prodetail
    } =  this.state

    console.log(prodetail)
    console.log(prodetail.firstname)
```

Comment: Is `firstname` actually defined within the response from the http request? Either ways, how does the response look like?

Comment: if first console returned data.. you should be able to see what is there and why second is not showing data. May be firstname is not present in proddetail!.

Comment: This the result of a direct api call: [{"ID":"e424a407-6619-4549-9036-670e0d517655","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}]

Comment: The first console.log show this [{"ID":"e424a407-6619-4549-9036-670e0d517655","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}]

Comment: The second console.log is undefined. I am thinking about where did I miss. Thanks

Comment: According to the data returned, the way you access "firstname" should be `prodetail[0].FirstName`

Comment: Thanks. I tried putting prodetail[0].FirstName and it returned TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined.

Comment: the first console.log result
[{…}]
0:
ID:"e424a407-6619-4549-9036-670e0d517655"
FirstName:"John"
LastName:"Doe"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

I am wondering if this format has anything to do with the second console log.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you're referring to the first render, it is expected.

On the first render, `prodetail` is just an empty string. Then only `componentDidMount` is invoked. On top of that, your `componentDidMount` is an async function, which will only set `prodetail` until `axios.get` is returned.

Instead, you might want to defer rendering data needed with `prodetail` until your request is resolved. For example

```
render() {
  const{ prodetail } =  this.state;

  if (prodetail) {
    console.log(prodetail[0].FirstName);
    return (
      <div>{prodetail[0].FirstName}</div>
    );
  }

  return <div>Loading</div>;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and is still print out as undefined in the second console.log  

render() {
  const{ prodetail } =  this.state;

  if (prodetail) {
 console.log(prodetail)
 console.log(prodetail.firstname)
    return (
      <div>{prodetail.firstname}</div>
    );
  }

  return <div>Loading</div>;
}

Comment: It will always be undefined on the first render. `prodetail` is just an empty string. Even so, according to the response returned from the API, it is an array, `prodetail.firstname` is still undefined, because it's just simply isn't there. If it helps, look at the updated answer based on what you have commented in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I will try my best. I am still new to React. I just started a few weeks ago. React is totally different from OOP concepts like C# or Java